# How do I overlay a textview over a glsufaceview(android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, hud

Ive been following the android opengl tutorials at http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/
and have searched on how to go about adding a hud type display. The simplest solution seems to be to overlay a textview over the glsurfaceview but I cannot find any examples online.Does anyone know of any examples??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply include both views in your layout, one on top of the other like so:

```
<merge>
      <your.package.YourGLSurfaceView/>
      <TextView .../>
</merge>
```